# On the Fourier transform of bump functions

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, harmonic-analysis

Let us call a non-negative smooth compactly supported function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is not identically zero a bump function. My question is: Does there exist a bump function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ for which the integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\hat{f}(\xi)\|\xi\|^{-2}d \xi$ is finite? Here $\hat{f}$ stands for the Fourier transform of $f$.

Comment: Do you want it to be absolutely integrable? In that case I think it is impossible because $\hat{f}$ would need to vanish at $0$ but $\hat{f}(0)$ is the total integral of $f$, which is positive.